# Timestamp resolution fails

Tags: java, datetime

I am working on a Spring-MVC application, for which I am working on a password reset program. In that, I am sending out a manually created token, which has the emailid:timestamp:secretkey encrypted as a token. While verifying the token, it fails at verifying the time, which is calculated for less than 24 hours. I am posting my code. kindly let me know what I am doing wrong :

ServiceClass :

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    private static final String HMAC_ALGO = "HmacSHA256";
    private static final String TOKEN_SEPARATOR = ":";
    private static final long MAX_AGE = 1_000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // 24h
     private static final String signKey = "secretvalue";
 @Override
    public void createToken(String username){
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(generateTokenStringPublicPart(username, timestamp));
        sb.append(TOKEN_SEPARATOR);
        try {
            sb.append(computeSignature(username, timestamp, signKey));
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
 private static String generateTokenStringPublicPart(String username, long timestamp) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(username);
        sb.append(TOKEN_SEPARATOR);
        sb.append(timestamp);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String computeSignature(String username, long timestamp, String secretKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(generateTokenStringPublicPart(username, timestamp));
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), HMAC_ALGO);
        Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_ALGO);
        hmac.init(sks);
     return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(hmac.doFinal(sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }

 public static boolean verifyToken(String token) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String[] parts = token.split(TOKEN_SEPARATOR);
        boolean result = false;
        if (parts.length == 3) {
            String username = parts[0];
            System.out.println("username in verify token is"+username);
            Long timestamp = Long.valueOf(parts[1]);
            System.out.println("Current timestamp of token is"+timestamp);
            String signature = parts[2];
            if (signature.equals(computeSignature(username, timestamp, signKey))) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp < MAX_AGE) {  // It fails here
                    result = true;
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Timestamp remaining is"+(System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp));
                    System.out.println("Time verificaiton failed");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Signature is not equal");
            }
        } else{
            System.out.println("Token parts are not 3"+parts.length);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Console output :

```
Token value is mymail@gmail.com:1416659092440:MUYLhJS24EIQv5f-Ak7TXyzWKZSjSFKjcmJkJx2SVew
username in verify token is mymail@gmail.com
Current timestamp of token is 1416659092440
Timestamp remaining is 173238774
Time verificaiton failed
Token verification failed
```

Comment: start by debugging your code and post only the relevant parts please.

Comment: Hello, I have posted only relevant part, which part you think is not relevant?

Comment: isn't that your token indeed expired? from above 173238774 < 86400000 fails and you land up in else part?

Comment: Everything out of verifyToken and the input string to that function

Comment: @almasshaikh i think you are right, meaning his problem is in creating the token

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem. Are you sure the system clock didn't change between creating and verifying the token? By the way, `createToken` method as posted here is bungled and doesn't really do anything.

Comment: @MarkoŽivanović : I already found the solution which is mentioned below(about the brackets). Yes, I am aware it is bungled as I didn't paste the other code which is using the method. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in Java multiply/division operations are done before add/subtract

try:

```
  if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp) < MAX_AGE) {
```

Definition of MAX_AGE is also wrong:

```
    private static final long MAX_AGE = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // 24h
```

Comment: i don't understand why did you think it will it work and who +1 you

Comment: downvote because add/subtract has higher precedence than boolean comparison

Comment: SOrry, your solution was right. I had restarted the server, the token got invalidated because of that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Akshay that make no sense

Comment: I am serious. I used a token link which was before the server restart. i have already tried for 3 usernames.

Comment: I'm glad to hear @Akshay if so accept the answer, ;)

Comment: @JordiCastilla i think he got it right because of the restart of the server, not because of the answer you gave

Comment: The definition of MAX_AGE as presented in the question must include a typo because it would not compile.

Comment: @NoIdeaForName : Nope, the answer helped. I had tried dozen times before without those brackets.

Comment: @Ashkay: Try it again with the same values that were failing. As the comment below your question said, the computed difference WAS > 24 hours, so it should fail. Those parenthesis, while harmless, are unnecessary. Another possibility was that the time on the server was changed, and the restart caused it to correct itself by synching with a time server.

Comment: @Akshay theese parenthesis aren't doing anything, and might mislead anyone who will read this in the future, plus, the second part of the answer is completely wrong! it's OK to write 1_000 in java

Comment: I didn't read the edit where he mentioned about 1_000 or 1000.